# Not sure why my jquery smooth div scroller isn't working

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

I'm using the smooth div scroller as seen in this site: http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/.

For some reason it's not working, and I'm not sure why. All I'm getting is a page of anchored images that don't scroll. 
Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="makeMeScrollable">
<div class="scrollingHotSpotLeftVisible"></div>
<div class="scrollingHotSpotRightVisible"></div>
<div class="scrollWrapper">
    <div class="scrollableArea">
        <a href="#"><img src="some-image.png"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="some-image.png"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="some-image.png"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="some-image.png"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="some-image.png"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="some-image.png"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="some-image.png"/></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.smoothdivscroll-1.2-min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="smoothDivScroll.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({ 
            mousewheelScrolling: true,
            manualContinuousScrolling: true,
            visibleHotSpotBackgrounds: "always",
            autoScrollingMode: "onstart"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
a img {border: none; }

#makeMeScrollable
{
    width:75%;
    height:60px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
  #makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea img
    {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        /* If you don't want the images in the scroller to be selectable, try the following
           block of code. It's just a nice feature that prevent the images from
           accidentally becoming selected/inverted when the user interacts with the scroller. */
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -o-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
```

I think it's probably something really simple that I've overlooked or not seen, but it's been a while and I haven't caught it yet.

**UPDATE**

Here is [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9HstK/) of my code
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try loading jquery before the other scripts:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.smoothdivscroll-1.2-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="smoothDivScroll.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({ 
            mousewheelScrolling: true,
            manualContinuousScrolling: true,
            visibleHotSpotBackgrounds: "always",
            autoScrollingMode: "onstart"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also:

CSS comments are just `/*` and `*/` not `<!--/*`

```
/* If you don't want the images in the scroller to be selectable, try the following
           block of code. It's just a nice feature that prevent the images from
           accidentally becoming selected/inverted when the user interacts with the scroller. */
```

UPDATE:

You're missing some (apparently vital) css:

http://jsfiddle.net/9HstK/2/

Comment: I can try. I haven't used jsfiddle very much, so I don't really know how I to include stuff that's local to my machine. This page that I'm creating right now is local to my machine just to see if it works, so it includes the jQuery files stored in my local computer.

Comment: @arthur.e.anderson I have updated with the css from the site or the scroller and it works fine

Comment: @AdamMerrifield, isn't the vital CSS that appears to be missing in the .css file that I included when I said <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="...filepath.../smoothDivScroll.css" />  ?

Answer (score 0):

Based off of your code snippet and the example provided on that website, it appears that you have your structure wrong.

Per the "[documentation](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/options.html)":

> Smooth Div Scroll adds elements when the scroller is created. These
>   elements are given CSS-classes. In most cases you don't need to alter
>   these - just go with the default values.

It appears in your snippet that you are manually creating these elements.  Those elements are added when the scroller is created.

```
<!-- the CSS for Smooth Div Scroll -->
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/smoothDivScroll.css" />

<!-- Styles for my specific scrolling content -->
<style type="text/css">
    #makeMeScrollable
    {
        width:100%;
        height: 330px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea img
    {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        /* If you don't want the images in the scroller to be selectable, try the following
           block of code. It's just a nice feature that prevent the images from
           accidentally becoming selected/inverted when the user interacts with the scroller. */
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -o-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
</style>
```

```
<div id="makeMeScrollable">
    <img src="images/demo/field.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="field" />
    <img src="images/demo/gnome.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="gnome" />
    <img src="images/demo/pencils.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="pencils" />
    <img src="images/demo/golf.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="golf" />
    <img src="images/demo/river.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="river" />
    <img src="images/demo/train.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="train" />
    <img src="images/demo/leaf.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="leaf" />
    <img src="images/demo/dog.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="dog" />
</div>

<!-- LOAD JAVASCRIPT LATE - JUST BEFORE THE BODY TAG 
     That way the browser will have loaded the images
     and will know the width of the images. No need to
     specify the width in the CSS or inline. -->

<!-- jQuery library - Please load it from Google API's -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- jQuery UI Widget and Effects Core (custom download)
     You can make your own at: http://jqueryui.com/download -->
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Latest version of jQuery Mouse Wheel by Brandon Aaron
     You will find it here: http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/demos -->
<script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Smooth Div Scroll 1.2 minified-->
<script src="js/jquery.smoothdivscroll-1.2-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- If you want to look at the uncompressed version you find it at
     js/jquery.smoothDivScroll-1.2.js -->


<!-- Plugin initialization -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Initialize the plugin with no custom options
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // None of the options are set
        $("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Where do I have my structure wrong?

Comment: @arthur.e.anderson - Do you manually specify the additional scroll elements as shown in your snippet?  The only element that should be manually specified is the parent div, `makeMeScrollable`.